# Getting a SPUser's title (as it is on Active Directory)

Tags: active-directory, spuser

I need to get the Titles (eg: Mr, Mrs, Dr) for SPUsers which are stored in a list.

The Title is not available on the SPUser object, is it possible to somehow get this information, assuming it is stored in active directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Job Title is part of the user profile, what are you trying to? SOme sort of sample code would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Eric, This was solved by looking at the User Profile Service (as you suggest :) ). Luckily the details of users are synched, so you can lookup a users title from the ups. Thanks for the response!